# Going back to the start function stops the script

Tags: python, recursion

I am making a program where you can login, logout and access some settings, but I seem to be encountering an issue after logging out. I'm doing the logout by just calling the function containing the login code, but when it reaches the logout state it just ends the script instead of going back.
The Code:

```py
    def main():
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
    
        if UserName == 'a':
            print ("Login successful")
            logged()
    
        else:
            print ("Username is incorrect")
            main()
    
    def logged():
        print ("starting system...")
    
    main()
    
    print("welcome to joop databases")
    
    def options(): 
        print (" ")
        print ("[1]", end =" ")
        print ("Settings")
      
        print(" ")
        Selection = input ("")
      
        if Selection == '1':
            print ("    Settings")
            print (" ")
            print ("[x]", end =" ")
            print ("close")
            print (" ")
            print ("[1]", end =" ")
            print ("Log out")
            print (" ")
            Settings = input('')
            if Settings == 'x':
                options() 
          
            elif Settings == '1':
                main()
          
    options()
```

Anyway I'm an absolute beginner, I started yesterday, so if you could give simple answers it would be much appreciated haha.

Comment: is the 2nd part of the code in a function?

Comment: It is very unclear where your last piece of code comes from, what it might be part of... Please provide a [mre]: minimal (as in remove all unnecessary code, like everything related to colorama that isn't part of the standard library, and that wont be installed on many systems) and reproducible (= a single code block that we can copy, paste and directly run)

Comment: @sittsering to be completely honest with you i'm not sure what that means, that portion of code is started with a def options and proceeds to tell you what you can pick, the code shown there is mostly that of a second menu, but all in all i'm not sure.

Comment: @Matt what i meant is starting from `if selection =='1' ... ` till the end `main()` , is it defined in a function? or is it a simple menu after calling the function `main()`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille the last piece is just that of the log out menu, as I stated i don't think that part necessarily matters here, it's just to show how it goes back, but ignoring the imports what makes it unable to pass main() the second time?

Comment: Again, please provide a [mre]. There is no way we can run your code to test it, so how could we help??

Comment: @sittsering im going to assume yes?.. idk, as I said im new to this and i don't know what it would mean if it was or wasn't, but it's all wrapped by a def options(): line which I think is what your asking?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille just made the edit, hope that helps

Comment: " a single code block that we can copy, paste and directly run" - So no, that doesn't help. Your problem clearly depends on the interaction of these different part that you don't show us.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I feel dumb now, i'm not entirely sure what your asking, I can send you all the code connecting those two processes but it's a lot and most of it requires the colorama.. other than that I don't know what to do..

Comment: @Matt yes, that's what I was asking. After loggin in successfully, you are calling the function `logged()`. after executing `logged()` what does it do?

Comment: Reduce the code to the essential: the same structure (same functions and function calls) with minimal functionality (for example: we don't need to enter both a username and a password, one is enough to test it, we don't need fancy color prints and menus, no sleeps...) , just the minimal prints to show where we are and what goes on. This will probably help you see things more clearly as well!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille there, that is basically as simple as my code gets while still being my code

Comment: @sittsering basically just makes it print "starting system", the rest just happens naturally following the code

Comment: yup, i thought so. the issue(misunderstanding) here is that after calling `main()` from your `option()` , it'll end. You are not calling the `option` again.

Comment: Now this is clear! ;) So, it's no surprise that your code doesn't loop, as there is no loop in it. Try to follow the code by hand with pen and paper to see what happens. You can also use a tool like [PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to visualize the execution path line by line.

Comment: Also, you could remove the long version of the code, it just makes your question confusing. Anyway, congrats for the edit with the minimal version!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm still not sure how I would fix this

Answer (score 0):

edit your code in here

```
import sys
def main():
    #your code
    if UserName == 'a':
        logged()
    else:
        main()
    
def logged():
    #your code
    option()

def option():
    #your code
    if Settings == 'x':
        #here i'm considering `x` to quit the program
        sys.exit() 
    elif Settings == '1':
        main()
    else:
        print("invalid input)
        option()

main()
```

The issue with your code :-
you are calling `main()`, if login successful, you are calling `logged()`.
Then you are calling `options()` with `setting=='1'`, it'll call `main()`. and again if login successful, you are calling `logged()`. But after this, focus will return back to the `option()` and so your code ends.

Comment: aye thanks, I believe this will work, but it's gonna be a lot of fiddling to get the rest of it in now aha.

Comment: This solution, though it will work for a while, has a very big flaw: it makes a lot of recursive calls, and as the recursion depth is limited, it will lead to a crash with a RecursionError. It would be better to implement a proper loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think recursion (calling the function inside itself) is a good way of achieving what you want. recursion is confusing and could lead to weaknesses in your code (for example a user could abuse the recursion limit and crash the program).

A loop is designed for these kind of tasks, try something like:

```py
while True:
    user_name = input('Enter Username: ')
    while user_name != 'a':
        print('Username is incorrect!')
        user_name = input('Enter Username: ')
    # The correct username has been entered!
    print('\nLogin successful!')
    print('Starting system...\n')
    print('Welcome to joop databases\n')
    while True:
        print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
        print('[1] Settings')
        print('')
        
        selection = input()
        
        if selection == '1':
            print ('    Settings')
            print ('[x] Close')
            print ('[1] Log out')
            print (' ')
            settings = input()
            if settings == 'x':
                continue
            elif settings == '1':
                break
            else:
                print('Anavailable Option')
        else:
            print('Anavailable Option')
```

Also a couple of notes:

- if you want to print a line break you can put '\n' in the string and it will put a line break there
- if the string parameter of input() is empty, you can just write input() instead of input('')